# Jquery how to add ( || ) or ternary operator in to $.grep Method..?

Tags: jquery, arrays

In my form, just i chekcing the values what has been changed after it loaded from server. for that i am doing this function:

```
$(checkBox).each(function(i,el){
            status.push($(el).prop("checked"));

            $(el).click(function(){
                var clickedIndex = checkBox.index($(this));
                var prevStatus = status[clickedIndex];

                if(prevStatus !== $(this).prop("checked")){
                    statusChanged.push($(this).val() + ( $(this).prop("checked") ? add.toLowerCase() : remove.toLowerCase()));
                }else{
                    var that = $(this);
                    statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
                        return value != that.val() + add.toLowerCase()
                    });

                    statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
                        return value != that.val() + remove.toLowerCase()
                    });
                }

                console.log(statusChanged);

            })

        })
```

in this function, on else part (statusChanged) i am calling the $.grep function 2 times as `"add"` and `"remove"` - in case if i write the function like this (that part alone )

```
var that = $(this);
statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
    return value != that.val() + add.toLowerCase() || that.val() + remove.toLowerCase() //not working
});
```

not working..? what is wrong here or $,grep will not accept the or (||) ternary operator, or any one give other short method.. pls

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"$,grep will not accept the or (||) ternary operator"*

Yes it will. `$.grep()` expects your function to return a boolean, but it doesn't care how you get the boolean.

If your question is how to check that the `value` is not add or remove then you can do this:

```
var that = $(this);
statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
    return value != that.val() + add.toLowerCase()
           && value != that.val() + remove.toLowerCase();
});
```

That is, test that `value` is not add *and* `value` is not remove - but it could be any other value.

It seems kind of yucky to be doing calls to `.val()` and `.toLowerCase()` every time the callback is invoked though, so I'd probably do something like this:

```
var val = $(this).val(),
    valAdd = val + add.toLowerCase(),
    valRemove = val + remove.toLowerCase();
statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
    return value != valAdd && value != valRemove;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, running this code:

```
statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
    return value != that.val() + add.toLowerCase()
});

statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
    return value != that.val() + remove.toLowerCase()
});
```

is **not** doing an `or`-operation (`||`). It's an `and`. If you filter a list on one condition and then filter the same list on a second condition, it will have filtered on BOTH conditions (an `and`); not on one of them (an `or`).

What you need to do is to use `&&`in your new code:

```
var that = $(this);
statusChanged = $.grep(statusChanged, function(value) {
    return (value != that.val() + add.toLowerCase()) && (value != that.val() + remove.toLowerCase());
});
```

**Edit:**

Also, like some of the other answers mentioned, you should be careful with the precedences. Wrap the individual cases in parenthesis (like I added above).

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with operator precedence; `+` has a higher precendece than `!=`.
Also the logic is faulty, you want to check that the value is *neither* the one or the other.

Try changing the line to:

```
return (value != that.val() + add.toLowerCase()) && (value != that.val() + remove.toLowerCase());
```

Reference: [JavaScript Operator Precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)